# How to get NULL value from IN CLAUSE in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

We can get results with `IN` clause if the matching record is exist.
Is it possible to get `NULL` value if the the record is not exist.

For example:

If `abc@example.com` and `xyz@example.com` exist in table and `pqr@example.com` does not exist in table

And run this `query`

```
 SELECT `users`.`email_id`,`users`.`user_id`
 FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email_id` 
      IN ('abc@example.com','xyz@example.com','pqr@example.com')
```

the result will be

```
email_id         | user_id
-----------------+--------
abc@example.com  | 1
xyz@example.com  | 2
```

But is it possible to get result in this form:

```
email_id        | user_id
----------------+------------
abc@example.com | 1
xyz@example.com | 2
pqr@example.com | NULL --or some value
```

Comment: Is there any master table which stores all possible email ids?

Comment: No, here the email comes from client side, 
Here share article with emails scenario like  
an user can share article to people with their emailID, and I am getting that bunch of Emails

Answer (score -1):

It is possible but not with IN, you could can combine this query that returns the emails in three different rows:

```
SELECT 'abc@example.com' AS email
UNION ALL SELECT 'xyz@example.com'
UNION ALL SELECT 'pqr@example.com'
```

with the `users` table, using a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT e.email, users.user_id
FROM (
    SELECT 'abc@example.com' AS email
    UNION ALL SELECT 'xyz@example.com'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'pqr@example.com'
  ) e LEFT JOIN users
  ON e.email = users.email_id
```

Comment: Here I am getting dynamic list of emails like

('abc@example.com','xyz@example.com','pqr@example.com')

How is work with that?

Comment: @aba there are no better ways of doing it using just SQL. You could create SELECT dynamically, or the only alternative is to use a programming language

Comment: Hey @fthiella you are right, may be I need to do it with programming language